# Biostrings gregexpr2 gives errors while gregexpr works fine

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, bioconductor

I'm replacing gregexpr with gregexpr2 to detect overlapping matches. When I try.

```
>subSeq
 3000-letter "DNAString" instance
 seq: ACACGTGTTCTATTTTCATTTGCTGACATTTTCTAGTGCATCATTTTTTATTTTATTTTCATT....

gregexpr2("TAAT|ATTA",subSeq)

Error in matches[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

whereas

```
gregexpr("TAAT|ATTA",subSeq)
```

works fine.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite clear if you read [`gregexpr2` documentation](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/Biostrings/html/gregexpr2.html):

> This is a replacement for the standard gregexpr function that does exact matching only. Standard `gregexpr()` misses matches when they are overlapping. The `gregexpr2` function finds all matches but it only works in "fixed" mode i.e. for exact matching (**regular expressions are not supported**).

I bolded the relevant sentence above. So, your `gregexpr2` searches for `TAAT|ATTA` text in your input, and since there is no pipe, no match is found.

If you need regex overlapping matches, use `str_match_all` from *stringr*:

```
library(stringr)
> x <- "TAATTA"
> str_match_all(x, "(?=(TAAT|ATTA))")
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]  
[1,] ""   "TAAT"
[2,] ""   "ATTA"
```

The `str_match_all` function keeps all the capturing group values (matched with `(...)` pattern parts), so you will collect all the overlapping matches due to the capturing group used inside a positive lookahead (that is a non-consuming pattern letting the regex engine fire the pattern at each location inside the string).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?=` -  start of a non-consuming [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that will trigger at each location inside the string

  - `(`  - start of a capturing group

    - `TAAT` - `TAAT` substring
    - `|` - or
    - `ATTA` - `ATTA` substring
  - `)` - end of the capturing group
- `)` - end of the positive lookahead.

Comment: Hello, that function works except it doesn't appear to give the locations of the matches. It just lists the strings themselves as far as I've seen. Is there something that gives the locations like gregexpr? Or do I have to use gregexpr2 twice?

Comment: @AD: If you need the start locations, you may get them with `str_locate_all(x, "(?=(TAAT|ATTA))")`. Or you need to run `gregexpr2` twice.